# Where and how, to find the installer file after creating and adding set up project to a solution having a windows application?

Tags: c#, installation, setup-project, setup-deployment, setuptools

HI,
   I have a windows application in C#. I created and added a set up project to this solution. Then, built the solution. I refered to this link **http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/SetupAndDeployment.aspx**. I even added the shortcut of "**Primary output of my application**" to "User's Desktop" folder. But I am not able to find the installer file in Desktop, so that I can "double click" this installer file and install my Windows application. 
                      **KINDLY HELP ME WITH THE PROCEDURE THAT NEEDS TO BE FOLLOWED AFTER CREATING A SET UP PROJECT, ADDING IT TO A SOLUTION AND BUILDING THE SOLUTION. WHERE AND HOW TO FIND THE INSTALLER FILE. IS THERE ANYTHING THAT I AM MISSING.**

Comment: Duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722076/where-and-how-to-find-the-installer-file-after-creating-and-adding-set-up-projec, the same author, already accepted. Consider dropping this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The installer file should be located in the bin folder of your installer project.  Right click on the project in the project tree, and select "Open folder in windows explorer", and you'll find the bin directory.

The link on the desktop will only be present once the installer file has been run.

Comment: Thank you so much. HATTS OFF for such a speedy reply. I found the installer (.msi) file along with the .exe file in the Debug file of my Set Up project. Can you kindly let me know if it is somehow possible to change the default installation location.( Ofcourse we can click on BROWSE and change the location but is there any way to change the default installation location itself; can you plz let me know this).

Comment: I don't have a setup project right now here, but I found this, and it reminds me what I did: "You can change the default install location for the file folder in the File System view of your setup project. In the properties it's the "DefaultLocation" property." (from http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/0755a58e-4fd4-4497-8454-18e65bd6f765)

Answer (score 0):

Whether this is 100% applicaple I don't know but it's something I'd think is worth a try which is if u know what the installer file is called why not do a search for that file to see if it's been stored somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I apologise If I am stating the obvious to you, I have probably misunderstood your question if i am.

When you make a setup project the built setup files are in the Debug or Release folder of the setup project depending on your build settings

-setup.msi
-setup.exe for example

clicking setup.exe will run the install the application

You copy them to the user's desktop and click to install your application?